# How do I filter Time in R (ITime)?

Tags: r, select, filter, dplyr, timespan

I have this blood pressure data set.

| date | time | systole | diastole | Pulse |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2020-12-04 | 07:38:00 | 117 | 83 | 65 |
| 2020-12-04 | 07:39:00 | 121 | 86 | 60 |

Time format is `<S3:ITime>`.

I would like to filter all systole and diastole values for a certain span of time. For example all systole and diastole values from 06:00:00 to 09:00:00 independent from date.

What I have tried so far:

```
   filter(bp,Time<08:00:00|Time>06:00:00)

   select(bp$Time<08:00:00|bp$Time>06:00:00)
```

I get errors like "numeric expression only has 9 elements and only the first one is used." I don't know what that means.

Is it because `dplyr` doesn't work with the time format I have?

Comment: Welcome to SO!  The `lubridate` package could be your friend.  [This](https://lubridate.tidyverse.org/) is a good place to start.

Comment: It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ITime` is from `data.table` package. To select rows between `06:00:00` to `09:00:00` you can do.

```
library(data.table)
result <- setDT(bp)[between(time, as.ITime('06:00:00'), as.ITime('09:00:00'))]
```